# Is it possible to upload a zip file via Assets?

Tags: assets

I have a need to be able to upload a zip file into assets. Is it possible?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can upload zip files from the main Assets table in the control panel as well as from an Assets field type assuming 1) you haven't removed 'zip' from the [allowedFileExtensions](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/config-settings#allowedFileExtensions) config setting and 2) you haven't restricted the allowed file types in the field's settings.